# How do I display the base of logarithms in Markdown?

Tags: markdown

Is there a way to display the base of a logarithm in (GitHub-flavored) Markdown so that it will be shown below the line?

I mean the number 2 in this expression: log2 n.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```html
you can write 
log<sub>b</sub><sup>x</sup>+log<sub>b</sub><sup>y</sup>
```

which displays

```
enter code here
```

log<sub>b</sub><sup>x</sup>+log<sub>b</sub><sup>y</sup>

Comment: this is the proper way to use log in markdown.

$log{_a}{n}$

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use math symbols and expressions in Markdown use this syntax `$<expression>$`

> I mean the number 2 in this expression: log2 n

Write `$log{_2}{n}$` in your markdown file.

Answer (score 1):

The base of a logarithm is displayed as a subscript. You can produce subscripts in Markdown using `<sub>`. Thus `log<sub>2</sub>(n)` displays log<sub>2</sub>(n).

Answer (score 1):

this is the proper way to use log in markdown.

```
$log{_a}{n}$
```